# pulls all Azure Active Directory (AAD) sign ins in the past 7 days

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory, azure-powershell

I am trying to get the last sign in logs in the past 7 days in the azure runbook, I have tried this code:

```
$SetDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-7);
$SetDate = Get-Date($SetDate) -format yyyy-MM-dd
$array = Get-AzureADAuditSignInLogs -Filter "createdDateTime gt $SetDate" | select userDisplayName, userPrincipalName, appDisplayName, ipAddress, clientAppUsed, @{Name = 'DeviceOS'; Expression = {$_.DeviceDetail.OperatingSystem}},@{Name = 'Location'; Expression = {$_.Location.City}}

$array
```

but its not working it shows me an error msg which says:

```
System.Management.Automation.CommandNotFoundException: The term 'Get-AzureADAuditSignInLogs' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

could anyone help ?

Comment: Have you installed the correct module? The Cmdlet is part of `AzureADPreview` module.

Comment: yes I have install it

Comment: So when you do `Get-Module AzureAD* -ListAvailable` you get 2 modules correct? AzureAD and AzureADPreview?

Comment: yes, the problem is that this code  Get-AzureADAuditSignInLogs not working

Comment: The AzureAD module will be deprecated in early 2023, just so you're aware. It would be prudent if building something new, to look at the newer Graph modules.

Comment: @h_akm Try running `Import-Module AzureADPreview` before calling `Get-AzureADAuditSignInLogs` then

Comment: I run it but still the same even when I tried the code on my Mac laptop in visual code it doesn't work is there any other code that can show me the last 7 days which employee login?

Comment: Import-Module: The current processor architecture is: MSIL. The module '/Users/.local/share/powershell/Modules/AzureADPreview/2.0.2.149/AzureADPreview.psd1' requires the following architecture: Amd64.

Answer (score 1):

Please check if **`AzureAD`** module is there or not by running below command:

```
Get-Module -Name AzureAD
```

If it still exists, try to uninstall it with below command:

```
Uninstall-Module AzureAD
```

After uninstalling **`AzureAD`** module , now install  **`AzureADPreview`** module and import it like below:

```
Install-Module AzureADPreview 

Import-Module AzureADPreview
```

Please note that, **`AzureADPreview`** module won't work if **`AzureAD`** module exists.

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the response successfully like below:***

```
$SetDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-7);  
$SetDate = Get-Date($SetDate) -format yyyy-MM-dd  
$array = Get-AzureADAuditSignInLogs -Filter "createdDateTime gt $SetDate" | select userDisplayName, userPrincipalName, appDisplayName, ipAddress, clientAppUsed, @{Name = 'DeviceOS';  
Expression = {$.DeviceDetail.OperatingSystem}},@{Name = 'Location'; Expression = {$.Location.City}}  
$array
```

**Response:**

[image]

I do agree with GauravMantri, if you are working on Mac.

Comment: even if I try to run it in the azure runbook? because also I got an error there

Comment: which version of powershell are you using? 5 or 7?

Comment: i am using 5 version

Comment: finally it works on my windows laptop yaaay. now I want to add more properties such as company name & the date in ISO 8601 format do you know how?

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting the error is because Mac is not supported for Azure AD PowerShell Cmdlets.

You would need to use one of the supported operating systems mentioned here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/active-directory/install-adv2?view=azureadps-2.0#supported-operating-systems.

Comment: I have tried to do the same steps in my windows laptop but when I run the code I got this problem Get-AzureADAuditSignInLogs : Error occurred while executing GetAuditSignInLogs Code: Authentication_RequestFromUnsupportedUserRole Message: User is not in the allowed roles InnerError: RequestId: df6f9a86-9f99-444d-a294-7687dd345f99 DateTimeStamp: Tue, 23 Aug 2022 17:03:20 GMT HttpStatusCode: Forbidden HttpStatusDescription: Forbidden HttpResponseStatus: Completed

Comment: This looks like a permission issue. Please check if you have proper permissions to perform the operation. Do ask a separate question for this issue and provide all the necessary details there.